# What is "state-object" in cgroups

Tags: linux, kernel, lxc, cgroups

I am gathering some idea about `lxc`, kernel name spaces and `cgroups`. While reading `man lxc-cgroup`, i find :

> lxc-cgroup  gets  or sets the value of a state-object (e.g.,
>   'cpuset.cpus') in the container's cgroup for the corresponding
>          subsystem (e.g., 'cpuset'). If no [value] is specified, the current value of the state-object is displayed; otherwise it is
>          set.

My initial idea about `state-object` is that it an instance belong to the given subsystem. Can anyone clarify please ?